# ¿Por qué no puedo importar iostream en C++20?

Tags: c++20

Estoy empezando a estudiar C++20 y no consigo importar iostream:

```
import <iostream>;

int main()
{
    int answer{ 42 };

    std::cout << "The answer to life, the universe, and everything is "
        << answer
        << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Es el primer ejemplo del tutorial y no compila ni en visual studio 2022 ni en code::blocks

Comment: Puede ser que tu compilador no esté haciendo uso del estándar c++20

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64877559/cant-use-iostream-as-module-in-c20-visual-studio

Comment: Eso no es problema del lenguaje sino del compilador. ¿Qué configuración estás usando? En teoría [los módulos ya están disponibles en Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/a-tour-of-cpp-modules-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: En principio, estaba usando estándar C++20, pero he tenido que habilitar la última versión tal y como señala el enlace de Cris223511.dev